# Присваивание строке элемента другой строки

Tags: c, строки

У меня есть строка `alf[]="0123abcd"` нужно сделать так, чтобы другая строка была равна `i` элементу из строки `alf`.

```c
alf[]="1234abcd";
res[100]=alf[2];
```

Не работает

Comment: [Работает.](https://ideone.com/aWq4fC)

Comment: Что значит *чтобы строка была равна элементу*? каждый символ строки был равен этому символу или чтобы результирующая строка содержала один этот символ и всё?

Comment: И да. прежде чем задавать тут вопрос, стоит прочитать хотя бы вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Вы смотрели как выглядит Ваш вопрос для участников? Как минимум, код стоило вставить как код, а не как текст, чтобы две строки не слились в одну. Также в названии вопроса стоит указывать его **краткое** содержание, а не полностью весь вопрос. Ну и, напоследок, язык указывается в метках.

Answer (score 1):

Если автор имел в виду, что следует сделать так, чтобы результирующая строка содержала один символ – `i`-ый символ исходной строки, то он сам прекрасно справился с задачей. Как заметил [@ДжонниКэтсвилл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/413516/%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB), всё действительно [работает](https://ideone.com/aWq4fC).

Однако, если автор имел в виду, что **каждый** символ новой строки должен стать равным `i`-ому символу исходной, предлагаю такое решение:

```c
alf[]="1234abcd";
char res[100];
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
{
    res[j] = alf[2];
}
```

Предоставить более подробный ответ не представляется возможным, т.к. на данном этапе автор дал довольно мало информации.

P.S. Если автор действительно написал в `main` только эти строки

```c
alf[]="1234abcd";
res[100]=alf[2];
```

и удивлён, что данная конструкция *не работает*, то, боюсь, SO здесь не помощник, и стоит почитать хоть немного литературы по Си для новичков.